# Difference between VOLUME declaration in Dockerfile and -v as docker run parameter

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Could some one help me to understand the difference between:

`VOLUME` command in `Dockerfile` (image building layer)

and

`-v` parameter when issuing `docker run`**-v**`/xyz/bla` command (container building layer).

`-v` parameter is for me clear, it simply exposes a directory from the host to the container and vice versa, but how does `VOLUME` in `Dockerfile` behave differently?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The `-v` parameter and `VOLUME` keyword are almost the same. You can use `-v` to have the same behavior as `VOLUME`.

```
docker run -v /data
```

Same as

```
VOLUME /data
```

But also -v have more uses, one of them is where map to the volume:

```
docker run -v data:/data # Named volumes
docker run -v /var/data:/data # Host mounted volumes, this is what you refer to -v use, but as you can see there are more uses,
```

So the question is: what is the use of `VOLUME` in a `Dockerfile`?

The container filesystem is made of layers so writing there, is slower and limited (because the fixed number of layers) than the plain filesystem.

You declare `VOLUME` in your `Dockerfile` to denote where your container will write application data. For example a database container, its data will go in a volume regardless what you put in your `docker run`.

If you create a docker container for JBoss and you want to use fast filesystem access with `libaio` yo need to declare the data directory as a `VOLUME` or JBoss will crash on startup.

In summary `VOLUME` declares a volume regardless what you do in `docker run`. In fact in `docker run` you cannot undo a `VOLUME` declaration made in `Dockerfile`.

Regards

Comment: Thank you, just to be sure, what I understood is, VOLUME will create a new volume inside the container directory as same as when using -v without specifying the path on the host. but that process is slow, therefore in some cases I cannot use VOLUME and I have to use -v because I need to specifify exactly where I want to save the files on the host, or just maybe to get better performance. that is the summery of what you said right?

Comment: Well, no. If you define a container without volumes and your application writes a lot, in a directory. This process not only will be slower than running the application outside any container also will be error prone. So the solution is to declare this directory as a volume, so writes will be directly in filesystem, as if the application runs outside the container

Comment: So the VOLUME path parameter is a directory on the host right? so that means the container will write the whole file system of the it into that directory? I.e., I will find /root /boot /etc /var ....... in that specified directory?

Comment: No the VOLUME path parameter is the directory in the container. For example /data. Docker creates a directory in the host for storing everything you write in the container in /data diretory. Check docker inspect for a running container with volumes.

Comment: Sorry but I am still confused, because I cannot find the difference between VOLUME and -v , so what I find now is they are the same, except I can determine the destination on the host using -v. If not could you just summerize that in one sentence maybe?

Comment: Yes this is the difference with -v you can determine the destination or state  it will store things in a named volume. But with VOLUME you can force creating the directory regardless the user do with docker run

Comment: AFAIK Volumes are always *created* on the host and *mounted* on the container. There are 3 types of volumes: bind, named and tmpfs (in-memory). With bind mounts you set where the volume is created on the host and can easily write to it *from host* (think dev mode).

With `-v`, at *run time* you can create all three types, however with `VOLUME` command in Docker file, only named volume is possible. See: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#notes-about-specifying-volumes. Why use `VOLUME`? To declare "there be named volume" which *cannot* be changed at run time via `-v` flag.

Comment: *oops, it's `--mount` that can create all three types, `-v` always creates bind mounts (but you can control the paths).

Answer (score 17):

### In a nutshell

The `VOLUME [PATH]` instruction inside a Dockerfile is equivalent to

```
$ docker run -v $(docker volume create):[PATH] [IMAGE_NAME]
```

### Detailed explanation

> The container filesystem is made of layers so writing there is slower and limited (because the fixed number of layers) than the plain filesystem.

**Using volumes in Docker is primarily less a matter of speed than a matter of data persistance independet from a container's life cycle.** Mounting volumes from a faster disk will obviously improve performance, but Docker's default behavior for `VOLUME` is to create a named volume on the host system with little to no speed improvements compared to the container's writable layer.

> `-v` parameter is for me clear, it simply exposes a directory from the host to the container and vice versa

**While this is partly true, `-v` can also be used to mount [named volumes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/) into your Docker container instead of a directory.** This little detail is important in order to understand what `VOLUME` does. An example:

```
$ docker volume create my_volume
$ docker run -v my_volume:[PATH] [IMAGE_NAME]
```

Here a volume named `my_volume` was created. It behaves as would expect from a 'normal' mount. Any changes to `[PATH]` inside the container will be persisted in this volume. The difference is that Docker manages the volume's location, so that you don't need to worry (it is `/var/lib/docker/volumes/my_volume/_data` in case you're interested). Why would you want this? You could have a test database. While you don't need direct access to the files, you might want to save the current state to mount it into other database containers.

The `VOLUME [PATH]` instruction basically saves the above instructions into the image's metainformation. So everytime you start a container from this image, Docker knows that you want to persist `[PATH]` in a volume and takes care of that.

Comment: My friend. First: VOLUME [PATH] is equivalent to docker run -v [PATH]. It doesn't create named volumes. Check the documentation: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/volume . Second VOLUME is used in Dockerfile to force the creation of a volume independently the intention of persistence. Try to run Jboss with libaio activated without a VOLUME on JBoss's data directory.

Comment: Of course you are right and I should have been more precise: If you start a container from any image where `docker inspect --format="{{json .ContainerConfig.Volumes}}" [IMAGE]` is not `null`, Docker will create a volume with a random ID as a name for you as can be seen in `docker volume ls`.

So in a nutshell: I felt from the OP's question, that coming up with an example would be helpful. I did not mean to say `VOLUME` creates a _named_ volume. I just used named volumes as an example for mountpoints whose locations are managed by Docker.

Answer (score 1):

For someone who come into this post and want to know the difference between `VOLUME /docker/dir` in dockerfile and `-v /host/dir:/docker/dir` in `docker run` command:

`VOLUME` can only map a dir we specificated in the container into the default(system assigned, usually the `/var/lib/docker/....` ) host directory. While `docker run -v` can specificate both the host directory and the container directory.