# Saving database state from library/postgres

Tags: docker

I understand that I can change the default folder of `postgres` image to point to a volume - in which case, clearly the volume will persist. But I didn't do that because I wanted to understand the default behavior of this image.

So I simply ran:

```
# in one terminal
docker pull postgres
# as a foreground process:
docker run -P --name dev_db postgres

# in another terminal
docker run --rm -it --link dev_db:dev_db /bin/bash
# in this container, I created some databases and added some data to them
# then:
# docker stop dev_db
# docker commit -m "Add data" dev_db postgres_with_data
```

I thought as a result, the new image `postgres_with_data` will contain the data I added; but it doesn't. Shouldn't it be saved when I commit the container? If not, where did it go, and how can I save it?

#### Update

Thanks for the answers. So if I understand correctly, anything written to `/var/lib/postgresql/data` after [postgres Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/master/9.6/Dockerfile) executes [`VOLUME /var/lib/postgresql/data`](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/master/9.6/Dockerfile#L52) disappears when I stop the container?

But [it seems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40174052/336527) the `VOLUME` command in Dockerfile is equivalent to `docker run -P --name dev_db -v $(docker volume create):/var/lib/postgresql/data postgres`. But I would hope a volume created with `docker volume create` doesn't actually disappear when the container is stopped; in fact, I assume it doesn't disappear even when the container is deleted based on the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#data-volumes):

> Data volumes persist even if the container itself is deleted.

What am I missing?

Comment: VOLUME is indeed a build time option that does basically what you have indicated. Another way to get an anonymous volume would be to do `-v /var/lib/postgresql/data`.

If you do a `docker volume ls`, you will see all volumes. If you do `docker inspect <container>`, you can see what volumes a given container has.

If you want to use an existing volume, you can fire up a new container using that existing volume, you don't have to create a new one.

Comment: @programmerq so the data does not really disappear, it's still in the volume on the local host right? It's just not included in any commits?

Comment: correct-- a `docker commit` only commits changes to the container's copy-on-write filesystem. A volume is an external location that is bind mounted into the container, and therefore not part of that copy-on-write filesystem. Things like stateful data should go in a volume so they can persist across several instances of a container.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run a container, Docker puts a writeable file system layer on top of the image layers for that container - if you make any changes in the writeable layer and commit the container to a new image, the change you made **will** be persisted in the new image.

But the `postgres` image stores database files in a volume, not in the writeable layer (see the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/b2317dd369030a5f3f030b1daa1fc80da3cab9e0/9.6/Dockerfile)) - so when you alter database data then that's outside of the container's writeable layer and the changes don't get persisted.

If you did this instead:

```
docker run --name c1 postgres touch /new.txt
docker commit c1 postgres-new
```

Then the `postgres-new` image will have the new file, because it was added to the container's file system not to a volume.

Comment: A far more eloquent explanation than mine, kodus.

Comment: Yes, the volume will exist when the container stops - even if you delete the container actually. Run `docker inspect <id>` and in the mounts section you'll see where the data is stored. It will be on the host machine, not in the container's writeable layer - which is why it doesn't get saved with `commit`.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if it is too late but if you want the data to persist inside the docker container you can point the pgdata dir at anything but where it points now... thus not looking at a volume and not resetting:

docker run -e PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/pgdata

rather than PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data

Works for me on the FROM library/postgres:9.5 repo.

Answer (score 2):

The changes you've made to the db are saved in a part of the container considered ephemeral by the container, and so does not persist when you commit the image. The only way to make these changes persist is by mounting this folder on a volume and reusing whenever you run a postgres container.

Comment: So something like `docker run -P -v /some_host_folder/:/var/lib/postgresql/data postgres`?