# When to use auto mapped Docker data volume

Tags: docker

What is the main purpose of Docker data volume created by -v option without specified host file? For example `docker run -v /data -ti my-image`. Doc says it creates a new filesystem mapped to host filesystem to persist data (at some random-ish location). I understand that. But containers also persist all data when they are stopped and started again. So what is the difference between persisted data in stopped container vs. data volume?

I understand use-case for its advanced usage to map specific host file with `-v /data:/data/host`.

Comment: Read this also for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40163036/difference-between-volume-declaration-in-dockerfile-and-v-as-docker-run-paramet/40163757#40163757 -v option without specified host file is equivalent to VOLUME in Dockerfile

Comment: Thank you, I have not thought about performance reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head:

1. If you are planning on using `docker commit` at some point, then an ephemeral volume like that can be used to intentionally prevent some contents from getting committed to the new filesystem image (because the contents of volumes are not preserved as part of the image).
2. If you will be generating a lot of temporary data and you are worried about filling up the root container filesystem, using a volume will give you more space (because your data won't be sharing space with operating system files).

Comment: What if I run new container with the same name? Does it create new volume or reuse the one already created? (Stil asuming -v option without specifying host folder).

Comment: It will create a new container every time.  If you want a persistent volume, you need to use the `-v <vol>:<mountpoint>` syntax, where `<vol>` could be a host path or the name of an existing volume created with, e.g., `docker volume create`.